# additional input complication due to auto-match bracket in Vim

Tags: cursor-movement

There are several plug-ins can accomplish this task, auto-add a closing bracket when we type: `(`, `[` or `{`.

But then the cursor will be in the middle of paired bracket, when we finish inserting, we need to <kbd>ESC</kbd>, `li` to continue typing rest of the content.

This is quite frustrating, just autocomplete one character, we need to type 3 additional keys, is there a way to get around this? I still want to keep bracket auto-pairing though.

Comment: No. Stay in insert mode and press `<Right>` or (most auto-closing plugins let you do that) `)`or whatever the closing character is.

Comment: Alternatively, you could try to create a mapping for `()`,`{}` (exact pair without anything in them) that will override the plugin functionality. But as @romainl said, the plugin should do this by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fleshing out @nobe4's comment, you could do this:

```
inoremap <expr> ) matchstr(getline('.'), '\%' . col('.') . 'c.')==')'? '<Right>': ')'
inoremap <expr> ] matchstr(getline('.'), '\%' . col('.') . 'c.')==']'? '<Right>': ']'
inoremap <expr> } matchstr(getline('.'), '\%' . col('.') . 'c.')=='}'? '<Right>': '}'
```

- `<expr>`: allows us to do a conditional mapping
- `matchstr(...)`: finds the character under the cursor

It will either insert the needed parin/bracket/brace, or pass over the one that's already there.

Comment: Thanks, that's the way I would go for. The easiest way to to type `<Right>` in Insert Mode, but obviously it is less efficient, since the hand need to left the main area to a corner. Moreover, for people who use HHKB pro, typing <Right> implies `Fn +'`, which is also sub-optimal.